# Is this the right way for mapping entities and dtos with using Mapper?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, mapping, automapper, mapster

I have a Layer as Services and added a class as Mapper and i want to put all of my mapping here.
and i'm using asp.net core 5 and Mapster for mapping
am i do right?
this is my Code :

```
public class Mapping
{
    public static void InitializeAutomapper()
    {
        TypeAdapterConfig<BookMark, BookMarkDTO>.ForType().Map(dest => dest.Id, src => src.Id);
        TypeAdapterConfig<Category, CategoryDTO>.ForType().Map(dest => dest.Id, src => src.Id);
        TypeAdapterConfig<Comment, CommentDTO>.ForType().Map(dest => dest.Id, src => src.Id);
        TypeAdapterConfig<Like, LikeDTO>.ForType().Map(dest => dest.Id, src => src.Id);
        TypeAdapterConfig<Post, PostDTO>.ForType().Map(dest => dest.Id, src => src.Id);
        TypeAdapterConfig<Role, RoleDTO>.ForType().Map(dest => dest.Id, src => src.Id);
        TypeAdapterConfig<Status, StatusDTO>.ForType().Map(dest => dest.Id, src => src.Id);
        TypeAdapterConfig<Tag, TagDTO>.ForType().Map(dest => dest.Id, src => src.Id);
        TypeAdapterConfig<User, UserDTO>.ForType().Map(dest => dest.Id, src => src.Id);
    }
}
```

Comment: I copied my code , I just need some help to how define Mapster for entities and DTOs in a separately part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not right... If the compiler doesn't yell at you... then something was wrong with the IDE itself.

As far as I can see, seems like we want to create a mapping config out of Mapster. Do it like this:

```cs
// Somewhere we could access IServiceCollection
var config = new TypeAdapterConfig();
config.NewConfig<BookMark, BookMarkDTO>.ForType().Map(dest => dest.Id, src => src.Id);
config.NewConfig<Category, CategoryDTO>.ForType().Map(dest => dest.Id, src => src.Id);
config.NewConfig<Comment, CommentDTO>.Map(dest => dest.Id, src => src.Id);
config.NewConfig<Like, LikeDTO>.Map(dest => dest.Id, src => src.Id);
config.NewConfig<Post, PostDTO>.Map(dest => dest.Id, src => src.Id);
config.NewConfig<Role, RoleDTO>.Map(dest => dest.Id, src => src.Id);
config.NewConfig<Status, StatusDTO>.Map(dest => dest.Id, src => src.Id);
config.NewConfig<Tag, TagDTO>.Map(dest => dest.Id, src => src.Id);
config.NewConfig<User, UserDTO>.Map(dest => dest.Id, src => src.Id);

// Register config as singleton, ServiceMapper as scope.
services.AddSingleton(config);
// Make sure we have Mapster.DependencyInjection package installed
services.AddScoped<IMapper, ServiceMapper>();

// Using it be like
public IActionResult MapsterStaticMappingTest([FromServices] MapsterMapper.IMapper mapper)
{
    var book = new BookMark();
    var bookMap = mapper.From(book).AdaptToType<BookMarkDTO>();
    return Ok(bookMap);
}
```

The code was wrote on .Net 5, Mapster 7.2.0

***UPDATE***

As I just look back the Mapster source, a new `public static class TypeAdapterConfig<TSource, TDestination>` was there... I don't remember that the last time I look it was there... So this is my bad... your code was totally valid.

Just for a note, static class `TypeAdapterConfig<TSource, TDestination>` make all change under [GlobalSettings](https://github.com/MapsterMapper/Mapster/blob/master/src/Mapster/TypeAdapterConfig.cs#L17). Which would stand there, still doing nothing if we're not make use of some `ServiceMapper`, which have a direct dependency on `TypeAdapterConfig` concrete type.

Comment: I used TypeAdapterConfig class that get two parameters as TSource, TDestination
Can you please guide me to find the mistake of my work

Comment: @MrCloner I just updated the answer, things went quite a few change since the last time I take a look at it. Mah bad (XD)